# Git pull on current branch

Tags: git, github

I am still getting used to my git knowledge.

Basically, our team lead recently made some changes on the main branch of our project while I work on the branch `feature/login` on my own local repo.

While working on this branch, I want to have the latest changes on the repo of my team lead to my branch so I can give him the latest code setup when I request for pull request. I tried `git pull` while I am still on my `feature/login` branch but it did not work.

How do I pull the latest changes on the repo on my current branch?

Comment: What type of error did you get when you pull the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fetch the latest state of the main branch.

```
git checkout mainbranch 
git pull
```

Now incorporate that into your branch. There are two main ways. I like to rebase:

```
git checkout feature/login
git rebase mainbranch
```

But some people prefer to merge:

```
git checkout feature/login
git merge mainbranch
```

Either way, now push to the remote and set up the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @matt's answer, which is entirely correct, but you might find that there are some additional steps (if you get conflicts between your feature/login branch and the main branch) as follows (by the way I prefer the "merge" option that @matt mentions):

```
git checkout mainbranch
git pull
git checkout feature/login
git merge mainbranch
```

At this point if you got any conflicts then you should resolve them, and then, (once resolved):

```
git add [the files that were in conflict]
```

And then ensure your remote feature/login is up-to-date for your pull request as you mention with:

```
git commit
git push
```